# How to convert a Bitmap Image to IntPtr in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, intptr

I made this from an example i saw, it never threw any error, but the image is displayed as grey.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
private unsafe void menuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = Utility.GatherLocalSettings();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = settings.SavePath;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Scan Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            byte[] openFile = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            fixed (byte* p = openFile)
            {
                IntPtr img = (IntPtr)p;

                frmContainer newScan = new frmContainer(img);
                newScan.MdiParent = this;
                newScan.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName) + " [Saved]";
                newScan.Show();
            }
        }

    }
```

PS: I checked the csproj to allow unsafe code in the build.

Comment: Can you post the code for frmContainer, or just its constructor that take an IntPtr parameter?

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
IntPtr pval = IntPtr.Zero;
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
try
{
    pval=bd.Scan0;

    ...
}
finally
{
    bmp.UnlockBits(bd);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to unlock the bits afterwards! bmp.UnlockBits(bd);

Comment: Agree! Thanks for the comment. For further reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133958/unlockbits-lockbits-and-try-finally

Comment: Mine was crashing until I changed the pixel format: BitmapData bd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to load a .bmp file. To do that, just use [Image.FromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx). Then, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: The question is about how convert a BMP to a IntPtr, maybe he must elaborate the file after, and some image elaboration have to be done with unsafe code